# replicate a ggplot plot functionality in seaborn

Tags: python, plotly, seaborn, plotnine

I am doing a linear regression on a few timeseries (different colors) and plotting the equation on the same graph. In R using `ggplot` and `ggpubr` this is very easy. here is the example and the output:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
economics_long %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, value01, color = variable)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_light() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F) +
  stat_regline_equation(aes(label =  paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~~")))
```

[image]

Is there a way to do this in python / `seaborn` without having to do the fit for each colour and making the equations by hand?

If not `seaborn`, which python charting package allow us to do this easily? `plotly`, `plotnine`?